# How to change /var partition online?

Tags: mount, bind

I have a Linux server with `/var` in XFS and I want to change to EXT4. There is enough space in `/home`, so I can backup all files in `/var`.

Is there a way to do it while the system in running ?

I think `mount --bind` and `mount --move` can help, but I cannot find an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems we cannot switch a Linux partition online while there is opened file.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't change the filesystem while the partition is mounted. You will first need to `umount <partition name>` and once that is done, you can use something like `GParted` to change the filesystem type to EXT4.

Comment: I think I can mount /var to read-only first. Since rsyslogd and screen are using /var, I cannot umount it.

Comment: You might be able to get away with that `umount -r <partition name>`

Comment: Yes, mount to readonly, and then, how to switch to backup ?

Comment: You can tarball all the files in the partition to home.. `tar cvfz /target/tarname.tgz ~/destination/tarname.tgz`

Comment: Did this information help you at all?

Comment: No. If I rsync /var to /home/var, how can I umount /var and let system switch to /home/var ?  mount --move /var /home/var and then umount /dev/sda3 ?

Comment: Do you have physical access to the server?

Comment: If you have direct access to the server, the best thing to do is get Unetbootin and burn GParted to a CD. Once that is done, plug in a CD into it and boot from the CD. That will keep the filesystems unmounted and then you can repartition them

Comment: So it cannot be done online. I have access to the server. Thanks for help.